# how to read text files in file made in applescript

Tags: shell, applescript

How would i read the text the user defined in pass.txt

This is What I have so far to test it you must make a folder on your desktop called test

but I bet most of you could have figured that out

```
set choice to the button returned of (display dialog "Login or Signup" buttons {"Quit", "Signup", "Login"} default button "Login")

if choice is "Signup" then

    set username to the text returned of (display dialog "Enter Desired Username" default answer "")

    do shell script "mkdir $HOME/Desktop/test/" & username
    do shell script "echo " & username & " > ~/desktop/test/" & username & "/username.txt"
    set pass to the text returned of (display dialog "Enter Password" default answer "")
    set input to pass
    do shell script "echo " & pass & " > ~/desktop/test/" & username & "/pass.txt"
else if choice is "Login" then


    set username to the text returned of (display dialog "Enter Username" default answer "")

    set y to username
    set z to "pass.txt"

    set x to "/Desktop/test/" & y


    words of {(read (POSIX file x) & "/pass.txt") as «class utf8»} contains pass -- true



    set pass to the text returned of (display dialog "Enter Password" default answer "")

else
    return 0
end if
```

Comment: Forgot to mention error "Can’t make {file \"Macintosh HD:Desktop:test:this_could_be_anything\", \"/pass.txt\"} into type file." number -1700 from {file "Macintosh HD:Desktop:test:this_could_be_anything", "/pass.txt"} to file

Comment: This is too much code and it's unclear what the specific problem is; also, amend the question, don't add comments. Try to provide a [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i am trying to make the read the text document located in a folder defined by what the user made the username when they signed up so i can make applescript determine if its the right password for the username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brackets are not set correctly. Try this:

```
read POSIX file (x & "/pass.txt")
```

or

```
do shell script "cat " & quoted form of (POSIX path of (path to desktop) & "test/" & username & "/pass.txt")
```

There are many other issues in the script anyway. Just a few tips, use...

-quoted form of pathes

-the -p option for `mkdir`

-the `with hidden answer` option for password entry

Comment: error "cat: /desktop/test/hero/pass.txt: No such file or directory" number 1 adds a : to the end